# Getting error message saying my class does not name a type when trying to overload the "+" operator

Tags: c++, namespaces, operator-overloading, friend

The part that is giving me an error message is in the implementation file when I wrote the definition for the friend function that overloads the operator +. It is saying Statistician does not name a type. But it is a friend function and is written in the implementation file where the header is included so I am not sure why it does not recognize this. Also I realize that I spelled statistician wrong for the file name, but don`t know how to easily rename a file in codeblocks.

```
//header file   
#ifndef STATISTICIAN_H
#define STATISTICIAN_H
namespace GREGORY_STOCKER_STATICTICIAN{



class Statistician{

public:
    Statistician();
    void next_number(double);
    void erase_sequence();
    int get_length() const {return length_sequence;}
    double get_sum() const{return sum;}
    double get_mean() const;
    double get_largest() const;
    double get_smallest() const;
    double get_last() const;
    friend Statistician operator + (const Statistician &,const Statistician &);


private:
    int length_sequence;
    double sum;
    double smallest;
    double largest;
    double last;

};

#endif

}


//implementation file
using namespace std;
#include "Statictician.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

namespace GREGORY_STOCKER_STATICTICIAN{

    Statistician :: Statistician()
    {
        length_sequence = 0;
        sum = 0;
        smallest = 0;
        largest = 0;
        last = 0;
    }

    void Statistician :: next_number(double num)
    {

        length_sequence += 1;
        sum += num;
        if(length_sequence == 1)
        {
            smallest = num;
            largest = num;
        }
        if (num < smallest)
            smallest = num;
        if (num > largest)
            largest = num;
        last = num;
    }

    void Statistician :: erase_sequence()
    {
        length_sequence = 0;
        sum = 0;
        smallest =0;
        largest = 0;
        last = 0;
    }

    double Statistician :: get_mean () const
    {
        assert(length_sequence > 0);
            return sum / 2;

    }

    double Statistician ::  get_largest() const
    {
        assert(length_sequence > 0);
        return largest;
    }
    double Statistician ::  get_smallest() const
    {
        assert(length_sequence > 0);
        return smallest;
    }

    double Statistician :: get_last() const
    {
        assert(length_sequence > 0);
        return last;
    }

}



//the part that is tripping the error message    
Statistician operator +(const Statistician &s1,const Statistician &s2)


{
    Statistician s3;
    s3.sum = (s1.sum + s2.sum);
    s3.sequence_length = (s1.sequence_length + s2.sequence_length;
    if(s1. largest > s2.largest)
        s3.largest = s1.largest;
    else
        s3.smallest = s2.smallest;
        if(s1. smallest < s2.smallest)
        s3.smallest = s1.smallest;
    else
        s3.smallest = s2.smallest;
    s3.last = s2.last;

    return s3;
}
```

Comment: To rename a file in Code::Blocks, right-click it in the Project Management (the pane at the left with all the filenames in it, in the default view), and choose "Rename file"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `friend` declaration in a class, declares the function in the smallest enclosing namespace. So your `friend` declaration actually declares and friends `GREGORY_STOCKER_STATICTICIAN::operator +`.  It does not declare nor friend `::operator +`.

But your code tries to implement `::operator +` outside the namespace.  This makes for an entirely different function: it will not be found by any code which tries to add two Statisticians together, because that code only finds the namespaced version. Further, it doesn't even compile (as you posted the error message under Arnav Borborah's answer): since `::operator +` is not a `friend`, it cannot access the private members.

So the simplest solution is in fact to put the `operator+` definition inside the namespace, so that it matches the declaration:

```
namespace GREGORY_STOCKER_STATICTICIAN
{
    Statistician operator +(const Statistician &s1,const Statistician &s2)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now you don't need to qualify `Statistician` either.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the full name of the `Statistician` class, like this:

```
GREGORY_STOCKER_STATICTICIAN::Statistician operator +(const 
    GREGORY_STOCKER_STATICTICIAN::Statistician &s1,const 
    GREGORY_STOCKER_STATICTICIAN::Statistician &s2)
{
    //....
}
```

Also, you shouldn't have namespace names that long, since it is really verbose (error prone from typos), and it encourages `using` statements, encouraging naming clashes based errors. 2 using statements for the code would look like this:

```
using GREGORY_STOCKER_STATICTICIAN::Statistician;
```

Which is better than the alternative:

```
using GREGORY_STOCKER_STATICTICIAN;
```

In addition, while you didn't mention error of this, your `if... else` blocks need braces, like this:

```
if(s1. largest > s2.largest)
    s3.largest = s1.largest;
else
{
    s3.smallest = s2.smallest;
    if(s1. smallest < s2.smallest)
        s3.smallest = s1.smallest;
    else
        s3.smallest = s2.smallest;
}
```

In your previous code, this code would get evaluated outside the block, which I presume you didn't want, even if doesn't make a difference here. As advice, always put braces of `if...else` blocks, for the sake of maintainability.
Also, since you made your `operator+` a friend function, it is limited to the smallest block scope, within the namespace. Make the `operator+` an actual member function, not friend, so it looks like this:

```
Statistician operator+(const s1& other)
{
    Statistician s3;
    s3.sum = (s1.sum + this->sum);
    s3.sequence_length = (s1.sequence_length + this->sequence_length;
    if(s1.largest > largest)
        s3.largest = s1.largest;
    else
        s3.smallest = this->smallest;
    if(s1.smallest < this->smallest)
        s3.smallest = s1.smallest;
    else
        s3.smallest = this->smallest;
    s3.last = s2.last;
    return s3;   
}
```

Also, the explicit use of `this->` is not required, I was just making evident that the variables were being taken from the current object.

Comment: Thank you for your help, that cleared up that problem however now that I added the namespace to everything it is telling me there is an error with my member variables being private.

Comment: ||=== Build: Debug in Statictician (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\Roger\Documents\c++ files\Statictician\Statictician.h||In function 'GREGORY_STOCKER_STATICTICIAN::Statistician operator+(const GREGORY_STOCKER_STATICTICIAN::Statistician&, const GREGORY_STOCKER_STATICTICIAN::Statistician&)':|
C:\Users\Roger\Documents\c++ files\Statictician\Statictician.h|57|error: 'double GREGORY_STOCKER_STATICTICIAN::Statistician::sum' is private|
C:\Users\Roger\Documents\c++ ..ect...

Comment: @CyanMagentaYellowBlack for help with that error message, see the solution I just posted.  (This solution and the other one both make the same mistake, leading to your error)